# How to calculate variance in R for a certain number of observations (not a whole column)?

Tags: r

I have a data frame, and I'm trying to calculate the variances (of a column variable) for the first 95 observations and the last 95 observations. Is there a way of doing this simply? I'm new to R...

Comment: Did the answer work for you? If so, maybe accept it?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose all columns of your data.frame `df` are numeric, you can use

```
sapply(head(df, 95), var)
sapply(tail(df, 95), var)
```

If only some columns are numeric, compute variance for those numeric ones:

```
j <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
sapply(head(df[j], 95), var)
sapply(tail(df[j], 95), var)
```